# Expressing "live somewhere in summer and live somewhere in winter": Particle usage

Tags: grammar, usage, particle-に, particle-で

So recently I've been following the advice of writing up a journal entry in Japanese every day, and I had a question about particle usage for a set of sentences I did.

> 祖父と祖母はメーンに住んでいます。でも、メーンの冬はとても寒いですから、冬にロサンゼルスに住んでいます。そして、夏にメーンに住んでいます。ロサンゼルスの夏はとてもあついですから。

My question is simply this, should I be marking summer and winter with the に or で particle to indicate that my grandparents live in Maine or Los Angeles during the season in question.

Comment: "In + season/month/year, etc." would be 夏に、9月に、2016年に etc., but here in your second sentence you use 冬**は** (or 冬には), as pointed out by Yuuichi. Look up **contrastive は** (取り立て助詞).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

に is correct. Your sentence is good and I think 冬はロサンゼルスに住んでいます is better because this sentence contrasts winter to other seasons.